# How to uninstall LLVM?

Tags: linux, llvm

I installed LLVM from source (using CMake and `make install`) but I am unable to uninstall it because there is no `make uninstall` avalaible.

This is LLVM version 3.5.2.

I use ArchLinux.

How can I uninstall LLVM in an automated way?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the [CMake FAQ / Can I do "make uninstall" with CMake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#can-i-do-make-uninstall-with-cmake) :

> ...Unix users could enter this command in the shell:
>
> ```
> xargs rm < install_manifest.txt
> ```

(after you `cd` to the LLVM build directory).

Comment: Note that it doesn't remove the symlinks